# JQuery Show and Hide an iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, iframe, toggle

I have this code:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("a#calculator").click(function(){
  $("div#calc_frame").toggle();
});
});
</script>
<p class="form_text" style = "color: #f26522 !important; font-size:12px !important;"> Not sure of the date in either English or Hebrew?<br> Click to show our calculator (will appear to the right) <a href="#" id="calculator">here.</a></p >
```

Targeting a DIV which is wrapped around an iFrame:

```
<div id="calc_frame" style="display:none;">
<iframe src="http://mountsinaiparks.org/digital-yahrzeit/wp-content/themes/yahrzeit-theme/dates2.html" style="width:100%; border:none; min-height:220px; padding-top: 35px;" ></iframe>
</div>
```

This method should work of I am using the Bootstrap query - but it is not. Have I written something wrong? I would like it to show and hide with the href.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: yes says $(document) not a function

Comment: Are you sure that you are importing jQuery then? i.e. `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` for 3.1.1

Comment: It seems because it is Wordpress you have to use jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  }); BUT - it jumps the user back to the top of the page.

Comment: Jumping back to the top of the page would be the default anchor behaviour, so add an `e` argument to your click handler and then call `e.preventDefault()`.

Comment: yes I added that just now :D Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This was my final code:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$("button").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
    $("iframe").toggle();
});
});
</script>
```

Works perfectly.